# Why can't I compile this C API (NeMo Spiking Neural Network Simulator)

Tags: c, compilation, neural-network

Hi I am trying to utilize this library http://nemosim.sourceforge.net to play around with Spiking Neural Networks.

I am new to C and C++.

What I've done is, downloaded the installer from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nemosim/

Installed.

I then wrote this program in main.c file:

```
#include<nemo.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    getchar();      
}
```

and compiled it using MinGW on Windows:

```
gcc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\NeMo\include" main.c -o main.exe
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from main.c:1:0:
C:\Program Files (x86)\NeMo\include/nemo.h:48:1: error: unknown type name 'nemo_
network_class'
 typedef nemo_network_class* nemo_network_t;
 ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NeMo\include/nemo.h:49:1: error: unknown type name 'nemo_
simulation_class'
 typedef nemo_simulation_class* nemo_simulation_t;
 ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\NeMo\include/nemo.h:50:1: error: unknown type name 'nemo_
configuration_class'
 typedef nemo_configuration_class* nemo_configuration_t;
 ^
```

Please help me.

It looks like nemo.h has problems, but I suspect I am missing something because I am a newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this code has a common error that occurs when C++ programmers migrate to writing C code. In C++, you can declare a `struct nemo_network_class` object by writing, for example:

```
nemo_network_class foo;
```

However, in C, the `struct` is part of the type identifier. You must write:

```
struct nemo_network_class foo;
```

---

Change this: `typedef nemo_network_class* nemo_network_t;`

... to this: `typedef struct nemo_network_class* nemo_network_t;`

Change this: `typedef nemo_simulation_class* nemo_simulation_t;`

... to this: `typedef struct nemo_simulation_class* nemo_simulation_t;`

Change this: `typedef nemo_configuration_class* nemo_configuration_t;`

... to this: `typedef struct nemo_configuration_class* nemo_configuration_t;`

---

After you've made these changes and confirmed that they work, please submit a bug report so that this solution gets pushed into production.